# How do I get clientHeight of parent element when `ng-cloak` is active

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in the linker for my directive....

```
pre: function preLink($scope, e) {
    var element = d3.select(e[0]);
    var height = element.node().parentNode.clientHeight;
    element
      .style({
        "border": "7px solid black",
        "min-height": height+"px",
        "background-image" : "url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/dostuff-production/property_assets/23107/yellow-stripes.png')"
      });
      element.select(".board")
                    .style("transform", function(d){
                        var ch = d3.select(this).node().clientHeight;
                        return "translate("+0+"px, "+(height/2-ch/2)+"px)"
                    })
}
```

And then in my code I have

```
<jg-body ng-cloak>
```

The problem is that `element.node().parentNode.clientHeight;` is 0 thanks to the ng-cloak. Is there a way to defer the link function till after the ng-cloak is removed?

**Update**

Based on feedback I tried this...

```
compile: function compile() {
        return {
            pre: function preLink($scope, e) {
                var element = d3.select(e[0]);
                $timeout(function() {
                    var height = element.node().parentNode.clientHeight;
                    element
                        .style({
                            "border": "7px solid black",
                            "min-height": height + "px",
                            "background-image": "url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/dostuff-production/property_assets/23107/yellow-stripes.png')"
                        });
                    element.select(".board")
                        .style("transform", function (d) {
                            var ch = d3.select(this).node().clientHeight;
                            return "translate(" + 0 + "px, " + (height / 2 - ch / 2) + "px)"
                        })
                })
            }
        }
  }
```

However, `var height = element.node().parentNode.clientHeight;` is still 0 and removing ng-cloak fixes it. I created an example [plnker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bIwbZ6mEGlQuo0SS9Wp?p=preview)

Comment: Even without ng-cloak you should use clientHeight iin $timeout, otherwise you will get wrong values for all dynamic elements. You should be very catious with such directives thow, especially if you have a lot of them on same page.

Answer (score 0):

> Would a $timeout or something work?

Yes , it should. Also note that you are checking the height inside the `pre` link which runs before directive will be compiled. Before it is compiled it will have no content

You should move the code to `post` link and probably use `$timeout` there depending on what `jg-body` templating does. Also if it relies on asynchronous data to render and then get height you have another issue to deal with that would need more code shown to sort out

Comment: I can't move it to post because post runs in reverse order. I need it to run the opposite in order to set the child's height to a computed one based on parent's

Comment: I have no idea what that means in higher level context or what specifically you are trying to do

Comment: As you can see I am using the parent height to set the child. However, I also set the parent height in the linker and since this is transcluded into the parent if I run the post instead of the pre the parentNode has a height of 0 because its link function has not fired to set it yet.

Comment: Create a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that represents your problem. There isn't enough code shown for us to know how the elements are rendered

Comment: Demo doesn't explain why the version with `no cloak` won't work or why you can't wait

Comment: Because if that is 0 then the height will get set to 0. Meaning it will be the wrong size. So the basic deal is make both say the height. Don't know how to explain it better than that.

Comment: Well neither your explanations or demo are making it easy to help. demo doesn't infer any parent node problems or give much indication of what exactly you need

Comment: I don't know how to better explain it then, both values should be equal one should not be 0.

Comment: But when I gave you a way for it not to be zero you said it wouldn't work but weren't clear why

Comment: I don't understand I tried your way it didn't work it is in the example.

Comment: Oh and if I set it to post it doesn't do anything different but I knew that wouldn't that was just a wrong suggestion